# Why is my pointer NULL? It should be the start of a linked list

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, null

I am trying to get a bunch of linked lists out of an array, so that I can traverse each list individually. I have a traverse node that is supposed to run through the array and act as each linked list when it gets to that list in the array

```
    edge<T> *traverseEdge = new edge<T>();
```

Here is the for loop I am using and how I am assigning the traverseEdge to each part of the array

```
    for(int i = 0; i < numOfV; i++)
{
    //cout << "in first for loop" << endl; // test
    traverseEdge = vertex[i];
    for(int x = 0; x < numOfE; x++)
    {

        //cout << "in second for loop" << endl; // test
        cout << traverseEdge << endl;
        cout << "traverse edge is the graph get vertex" << endl; // test
        while(traverseEdge -> next != NULL)
        {
            cout << "in while loop" << endl;
            if(traverseEdge -> weight == ascending[x])
            {
                edge<int> *newEdge = new edge<int>(traverseEdge -> source, traverseEdge -> destination, traverseEdge -> weight);
                minSpanTree -> insertEdge(newEdge);
                cout << "edge added" << endl; // test
            }
            cout << "seg fault test" << endl; // test
            traverseEdge = traverseEdge -> next;
        }
    }
}
```

Every time it runs through the loop it never gets into the while loop because it is pointing to NULL even though I have filled the array here:

```
template<class T>
void wcuGraph<T>::insertEdge(edge<T>* currentEdge)
{
//cout << "In insert method" << endl; //test gate 11
    edge < T > *inverseEdge = new edge<T>();
    edge < T > *traverseEdge = new edge<T>();
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfV; i++)
    {
        //bool timeForInverseEntry = false;
        //adds source to destination connection
        traverseEdge = vertex[i];
        if (currentEdge->source == i)
        {
            //cout << "In first If" << endl; // test gate 12
            //traverses list and gets to end to add next edge(node)
            while (traverseEdge->next != NULL)
            {
                //cout << "Vertex next does not equal NULL" << endl; // test gate 13a
                traverseEdge = traverseEdge->next;
            }
            traverseEdge->next = currentEdge;
            //timeForInverseEntry = true;
        }
        //adds destination to source connection
        if (currentEdge->destination == i)
        {
            //cout << "In second If" << endl; // test gate 13
            //swaps destination and source for other half of undirected graph
            inverseEdge->source = currentEdge->destination;
            inverseEdge->destination = currentEdge->source;
            inverseEdge->weight = currentEdge->weight;
            //traverse list and gets to end to add next edge(node)
            while (traverseEdge->next != NULL)
            {
                //cout << "Vertex next does not equal NULL" << endl; // test gate 13b
                traverseEdge = traverseEdge->next;
            }
            traverseEdge->next = inverseEdge;
            //break;
        }
    }
//cout << "End of insert" << endl;
}
```

Here assigning the traverseEdge to vertex[i] worked perfectly and I don't know why it's not working in my kruskal method. The output I get when outputting the pointer is along the lines of this 0x7ffb70403a10.  I just need to know how to set traverseEdge = vertex[i] like I did in my insert method.

Heres how vertex was created.

```
    edge<T> **vertex;
```

Then in the constructor

```
    vertex = new edge<T>*[vertices];
    vertex[i] = new edge<T>();
```

EDIT MCV

```
    traverseEdge = vertex[i]
```

This for some reason is not setting the pointer traverseEdge to the pointer in the array and instead is setting it to 0x7ffb70403a10.  In my insert method this line of code worked perfectly. But in another method this code does not work and I don't understand why.

```
    for(int x = 0; x < numOfE; x++)
    {

        //cout << "in second for loop" << endl; // test
        cout << traverseEdge << endl;
        //cout << "traverse edge is the graph get vertex" << endl; // test
        while(traverseEdge -> next != NULL)
        {
            //cout << "in while loop" << endl;
            if(traverseEdge -> weight == ascending[x])
            {
                edge<int> *newEdge = new edge<int>(traverseEdge -> source, traverseEdge -> destination, traverseEdge -> weight);
                minSpanTree -> insertEdge(newEdge);
                //cout << "edge added" << endl; // test
            }
            //cout << "seg fault test" << endl; // test
            traverseEdge = traverseEdge -> next;
        }
    }
}
```

I am using this chunk to test what the output is. All of the parts I am using are included in my first post.  It gets into both for loops but because the pointer for some reason is set to NULL and not set to the linked list in the array it will not go into the while loop.

Comment: It will be better if you can post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Is this: `vertex[i] = new edge<T>();` supposed to be in a `for` loop? If not, you've got a problem. You're only assigning 1 edge.

Comment: It looks like you have a few memory leaks. You allocate for `traverseEdge` and then almost immediately reassign it without deleting the allocated memory in the meantime.

Comment: It is only supposed to be one edge and that edge has a pointer to the next edge. First for loop gets to the right linked list in the array then the second for loop runs through all of the possible edge weights in that linked list.

Comment: Reading down further, you seem to have missed part of the MCVE, specifically complete. I'd read @RSahu 's link again.

Comment: Your pointer isn't "pointing to NULL". Your pointer *is* NULL, which means it's not pointing to anything.

Comment: Why is it null then? That is the question. It isn't null in the insert method, but when I set it equal to something in my other method it is null for some reason.  I know I have memory leaks and I'm really not concerned about that right now.